# Using LAPACKE_zgetrs with LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR causes illegal memory access

Tags: c, lapack, lapacke

I am trying to solve a linear system using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

int main () {
    lapack_complex_double mat[4];
    lapack_complex_double vec[2];
    lapack_int p[2];

    mat[0] = lapack_make_complex_double(1,0);
    mat[1] = lapack_make_complex_double(1,0);
    mat[2] = lapack_make_complex_double(1,0);
    mat[3] = lapack_make_complex_double(-1,0);

    vec[0] = lapack_make_complex_double(1,0);
    vec[1] = lapack_make_complex_double(1,0);

    LAPACKE_zgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 2, 2, mat, 2, p);
    LAPACKE_zgetrs(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'N', 2, 1, mat, 2, p, vec, 2);

    printf("%g %g\n", lapack_complex_double_real(vec[0]),
        lapack_complex_double_imag(vec[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

For some reasons, this causes illegal memory access in `LAPACKE_zgetrs` (as detected by `valgrind` and by my big program crashing in `zgetrs` because of *"glibc detected corruption or double free"*). I did not include this in my SSCCE for brevity, but all `LAPACKE` routines that return, return 0.

The same code with `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` runs and valgrinds flawlessly.

My lapacke, lapack etc. is self-built for Ubuntu 12.04. I used the following settings in the lapack CMake file:

```
BUILD_COMPLEX       ON
BUILD_COMPLEX16     ON
BUILD_DOUBLE        ON
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS   ON
BUILD_SINGLE        ON
BUILD_STATIC_LIBS   ON
BUILD_TESTING       ON
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE    Release
LAPACKE             ON
LAPACKE_WITH_TMG    ON
```

and the rest (the optimized blas/lapack and xblas) off. There were no errors during the build and all tests succeeded.

Where did I mess up?

**Edit:** I just tried this with Fedora21 and the packaged lapacke. It did *not* reproduce the error.

**Edit 2:** While it does not reproduce the memory fails, it produces a wrong solution, namely `(1 + 0I, 1 + 0I)` for the above input (should be `(1,0)`)

Comment: I found [this thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/499788) which indicates an error in LAPACKE with row major packing when computing a cholesky factorization. I am unsure if `zgetrf`performs one, and if it triggers a similar bug, but it seems possible, given you want to have an LU decomposition.

Comment: @martin the cholesky factorization is the LL^T decomposition.

Comment: @ctheo yes, which still is a special case of a LU decomposition beneficial in some cases. But you are right, the matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: In any case, the thread mentions a bug in a transposition in case of symmectric matrices which this could still be (and I think that it has to be a bug in either LAPACK or LAPACKE because it otherwise doesn't make sense that it works in column major mode but not in row major mode)

Comment: @martin It is not really a special case since one of the results of the the LU-decomposition will be 1 on the diagonal, unlike cholesky. But yeah, probably a bug.

Comment: Did you try the mentioned version with the fix incorporated?

Comment: @martin Yes, using `LAPACK_COL_MAJOR` and the solving `'T'` instead of `'N'` appears to work.

Comment: I checked it with my build and works fine in both cases. Also `valgrind` reports nothing. Which version of LAPACK do you use?

Comment: @ctheo 3.5. as downloaded and built yesterday. Maybe I did something wrong building the lib, that's why I included the build details in the options.

Comment: Just as a clarification: Both `ROW_MAJOR` with `T` and `COL_MAJOR` with `N` work? And the other combinations don't work?

Comment: No, I needed a workaround to get my stuff done, so I ditched `ROW_MAJOR` completely and pretended that the matrix is `COL_MAJOR`, then fixed that lie by using `'T'` instead. I believe this mathematically is the same thing in the end. For my application, I only cared about the solution, not the decomposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and overthinking things, I found the culprit:

Using `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR` switches the meaning of the `ld*` leading dimension parameters. While the leading dimension of a normal Fortran array is the numbers of *rows*, switching to `ROW_MAJOR` switches its meaning to the number of *columns*. So the correct calls (giving correct results) would be:

```
LAPACKE_zgetrs(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'N', 2, 1, mat, 2, p, vec, 1);
```

where the second `2` is the number of *columns* (not rows!) of `mat`, and the last parameter must equal the number of right hand sides `nrhs` (not the number of variables!). I isolated this very call because all the other calls in my project dealt with square matrices, so the "wrong" calls do not have any negative effect due to symmetry.

As usual, if you are skipping columns at the end, the leading dimensions get bigger accordingly, as they would with skipping rows in the normal setting.

Obviously, this is not mentioned in the Fortran documentations. Unfortunately, I did see no such remark in the Lapacke documentation, which would have saved me a couple of hours of my life. :)